# User-defined unit macros with qualifiers break when used in fractional units

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following MWE with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}
\DeclareSIQualifier\peak{p}
\DeclareSIUnit\wattp{\watt\peak}
\DeclareSIUnit\usd{USD}

\begin{document}
\SI{41}{\usd/\wattp}

\SI{41}{\wattp}

\SI{41}{\usd \wattp}

\SI{41}{\usd\per\wattp}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image: siunitx output]

It appears that fractional representation breaks the functionality of qualifiers in user-defined unit macros. How can I get around this?

Unfortunately, protecting the `\peak` qualifier with the `\protect` macro (`\DeclareSIUnit\wattp{\watt\protect\peak}`) breaks *all* of the output:

[image: with protection]

I would like to have "W_p" (see the 2nd, 3rd and 4th examples from the original output) appear in the fractional unit (1st example) also.

Comment: As a side note, qualifiers should be avoided in units. It's the quantity that should be qualified, not the unit. Put it in another way, a metre is a metre whether you measure length or breadth (and a volt is a volt whether you measure rms or peak voltages etc.) ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: so you mean I should do this, instead: '\SI{41}{\usd/\watt\peak}'

Comment: @StephenBosch: Perhaps you should show us what you expect from this!

Comment: No, the quantity is the power, so you can write, e.g., $P_\textup{max} = \SI{41}{\watt}$, or $V_\textup{rms} = \SI{10}{\volt}$ instead of $V = \SI{10}{\volt\rms}$

Comment: See, e.g. the [SI brochure, §5.3.2](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-2.html), especially the side note.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I realise that is formally more correct, but in some industries, the notation I am using is a de-facto standard. Say you have tabular data with a unit column. It's unwieldy to put an equation where the units would normally go.

Comment: I didn't know the context, but I know that that of qualifying units is, unfortunately, a widespread practice, also in non-industrial settings. What I'd do is to write in the column header  '\si{\usd/\watt}' (without any qualifier), and then specifying in the table caption that it's the price (?) per unit peak power (or whatever).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I'll give your comments some thought and see if there isn't a better, standards-compliant way to communicate the information.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: the output is exactly as it should be. In your first use, you've forced 'literal' mode, where they always appear parenthetically. In the other cases you are in 'symbolic' mode. If you want `siunitx` to know the unit is reciprocal in symbolic mode use `\per` not `/`.

Comment: PS: of course, as a metrologist, I try to explain what would (hopefully) be the correct way to write quantities and units according to the SI, but I know that in several fields there are consolidated practices that no standard will modify, and sticking to the standard might end up in being misunderstood by one's peers. So, mine are just suggestions to be weighed according to the traditions.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm sorry, I didn't realise the parenthetical qualifier was expected behaviour, though it makes sense now that you've explained it. I was trying to get the qualifier subscripted in literal mode also. Upon reflection, it might well be better to let siunitx do what it normally does and use the parenthetical qualifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to protect your `\peak` qualifier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}
\DeclareSIQualifier\peak{p}
\DeclareSIUnit\wattp{\watt\protect\peak}
\DeclareSIUnit\usd{USD}

\begin{document}
\SI{41}{\usd/\wattp}

\SI{41}{\wattp}

\SI{41}{\usd \wattp}

\SI{41}{\usd\per\wattp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. See my edits. Any other ideas?

Comment: You should never need `\protect` with `siunitx` commands as everything is engine-protected.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, probably, but at the time of writting the question was unclear.